# Trying to build project with parcel, but keep running into unsupported file type error

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, parceljs

I am trying to build a project with parcel. I have followed all the instructions from my assignment, yet this error keeps showing up on my terminal whenever I try to run:

```
parcel src/index.html
```

This is the error message:

Build failed.

> @parcel/core: Unexpected output file type .html in target "main"
>
> C:\Users\johan\myflix-client\package.json:4:11
> 3 |   "version": "1.0.0",
>
> > 4 |   "main": "src/index.html",
> > |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File extension must be .js, .mjs, or .cjs
> > 5 |   "scripts": {
> > 6 |     "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"
>
> ℹ The "main" field is meant for libraries. If you meant to output a
> .html file, either remove the "main" field or choose a
> different target name.

I have even tried to remove the "main" altogether even though I was told that I needed it there, and it just throws more errors.

Please any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As the error indicates, `"main"` is used to refer to scripts. You cannot have it refer to an HTML file. Change that to be .js, .mjs, or .cjs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In package.json, you can try changing "main" to "default":

"default": "index.html"

Comment: Setting this like `"default": "mydir/index.html"` doesn't seem to work. `mydir` stays empty

Answer (score 1):

changing "main" to "default" (in package.json) fixed the problem for me!